# Ошибка при тестировании Filter

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, filter, mockito, mock

когда тестирую CharsetFilter вылетает ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()" because "this.request" is null
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CharsetFilterTest {

    CharsetFilter filter;

    @Mock
    FilterChain chain;

    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        filter = new CharsetFilter();
    }
    @Test
    public void doFilterSetEncodingToRequest() throws ServletException, IOException {

        when(request.getCharacterEncoding()).thenReturn("UTF-8");

        filter.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        assertEquals("UTF-8", request.getCharacterEncoding());
    }
}
```

что можете посоветовать?

Comment: инициализировать переменную `request`

Comment: каким образом? это же  mock, я ему в when задаю значение

Comment: По какой-то причине моки не создались и `request` в тесте `null`.

Comment: все заработало, просто переделал без анотаций